# xarray DataArray.where() reduced coordinate when masking

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

xarray novice here. Very simple case, I have a precipitation type array (ntim x nlat x nlon) and a total precipitation array (same dimensions). Both are in separate netCDF files. I want to mask the precipitation array where A) precipitation is falling (> 1e-8 m/s rate) and B) the precipitation type is snow (maskvar = 0.0). The output array is therefore a "where is it snowing?" array.

When using xarray where() with multiple conditions from two different (but same-sized) arrays, only two latitudes persist (north and south pole) in the resulting masked array.

However, if I use a pre-masked array (from NCL, written as netCDF w/ same dims) as a test, it behaves as expected (i.e., returns ntim x nlat x nlon) array.

The only obvious thing that sticks out to me are that the lat coordinate is not identically typed between both arrays, although it's unclear why that would cause this to fail in this manner.

Any help appreciated.

Sample code:

```
ensnum='001'
indir  = '/glade/u/home/zarzycki/scratch/LENS-snow/'
files  = [indir+'/b.e11.B20TRC5CNBDRD.f09_g16.'+ensnum+'.cam.h2.PTYPE.1990010100Z-2005123118Z.nc']
indir2 = '/glade/p_old/cesmLE/CESM-CAM5-BGC-LE/atm/proc/tseries/hourly6/PRECT/'
files2 = [indir2+'/b.e11.B20TRC5CNBDRD.f09_g16.'+ensnum+'.cam.h2.PRECT.1990010100Z-2005123118Z.nc']
indir3 = indir
files3 = [indir3+'/b.e11.B20TRC5CNBDRD.f09_g16.'+ensnum+'.cam.h2.PRECT_SNOW.1990010100Z-2005123118Z.nc']

for idx, val in enumerate(files):
  ds  = xr.open_dataset(files[idx])
  ds2 = xr.open_dataset(files2[idx])
  ds3 = xr.open_dataset(files3[idx])

  ptype  = ds.PTYPE[1:11,:,:]         # 10 time x 192 lat x 288 lon
  prect1 = ds2.PRECT[1:11,:,:]        # 10 time x 192 lat x 288 lon
  prect2 = ds3.PRECT_SNOW[1:11,:,:]   # 10 time x 192 lat x 288 lon
  print('---------')
  print(ptype)
  print(prect1)
  print(prect2)

  ptype1 = ptype.where((ptype > -0.1) & (ptype < 0.1) & (prect1 > 1e-8))
  ptype2 = ptype.where((ptype > -0.1) & (ptype < 0.1) & (prect2 > 1e-8))
  print('---------')
  print(ptype1)
  print(ptype2)
```

Sample output showing that all read vars are (time: 10, lat: 192, lon: 288) but returned masked vars are (time: 10, lat: 2, lon: 288) and (time: 10, lat: 192, lon: 288)

```
---------
<xarray.DataArray 'PTYPE' (time: 10, lat: 192, lon: 288)>
[552960 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 -90.0 -89.0576 -88.1152 -87.1728 -86.2304 -85.288 ...
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 6.25 7.5 8.75 10.0 11.25 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01T12:00:00 1990-01-01T18:00:00 ...
<xarray.DataArray 'PRECT' (time: 10, lat: 192, lon: 288)>
[552960 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -90.0 -89.06 -88.12 -87.17 -86.23 -85.29 -84.35 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 6.25 7.5 8.75 10.0 11.25 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01T12:00:00 1990-01-01T18:00:00 ...
Attributes:
    units:         m/s
    long_name:     Total (convective and large-scale) precipitation rate (liq...
    cell_methods:  time: mean
<xarray.DataArray 'PRECT_SNOW' (time: 10, lat: 192, lon: 288)>
[552960 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 -90.0 -89.0576 -88.1152 -87.1728 -86.2304 -85.288 ...
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 6.25 7.5 8.75 10.0 11.25 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01T12:00:00 1990-01-01T18:00:00 ...
Attributes:
    units:    m/s
---------
<xarray.DataArray (time: 10, lat: 2, lon: 288)>
array([[[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]],

       ..., 
       [[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -90.0 90.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 6.25 7.5 8.75 10.0 11.25 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01T12:00:00 1990-01-01T18:00:00 ...
<xarray.DataArray (time: 10, lat: 192, lon: 288)>
array([[[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        ..., 
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        ..., 
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]],

       ..., 
       [[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        ..., 
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        ..., 
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 -90.0 -89.0576 -88.1152 -87.1728 -86.2304 -85.288 ...
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 6.25 7.5 8.75 10.0 11.25 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01T12:00:00 1990-01-01T18:00:00 ...
```

Comment: It looks like the latitude coordinates in the datasets differ by a small amount. This is likely causing the coordinate alignment to behave differently than you expect. You could try using the `reindex` method to align these variables before using them for masking.

Comment: Yes, that apparently is the issue. I can use NCO to convert the dimension types from doubles -> floats (in the middle file) and that solves the problem. Alternatively, using `reindex_like` seems to also solve the issue (to force the coords to match) although I haven't verified the final answer is BFB what I want. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad my comment has helped point you in the right direction. If you get a chance to post your solution in a full answer, I'm sure others will find your solution useful in the future.